# Another RegEx to match wanted result

Tags: regex

I'm having another issue where I want to extract values from a string. Please take a look.

```
string anotherTest = "Hello World [A12345 **(05,00,45)**] - [518.6Z] [51.5]"
```

I would like the result to return "A12345" "518.6Z" "51.5".

What I highlighted in bold is what I'm having issue with.

I'm using c# and I've tried [(\D?\d+.?\d+\D?)] ... which is fine if I don't have what's in parentheses.

Comment: Match anything between `[` and `]` and discard the first result.

Comment: so you don't want the part in the `()` but you do want the `A12345`?  Is there a pattern to that number that is predictable? Like does it always start with a letter followed by a number?

Comment: What language are you using? [*What have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried that isn't working for you, and explain how it's not working?

Comment: Such a question without the regex flavor makes small sense. It's important to know if the lookbehind is possible, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the first word from a `[ ... ]` substring. Use groups:

```
.*?(\[([^\[\] ]+).*?\])*
```

Then extract second group from all the captures (depending on your langauge)

Comment: thanks for your answer. This was the closest that helped me. What I did was split the string by the hyphen then from there used regex to extract the values.